# Use plain text instead of mentions to define user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here is the code for the command:

```
if (command === "avatar") {
  let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`${user.username}`)
    .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL)
    .setColor(0x842cfc);
  message.channel.send(embed),
}
```

This command shows the avatar of a specified user, but with how it is now, you have to tag the specified user (making them receive a notification) to show the avatar. Right now the command is `.avatar @someuser` but I want the command to be `.avatar someuser`, so it doesn't mention them.
Also, I'm pretty sure I need to use `client.users.find()` somehow but idk how to. Thank you for any help!

Comment: The option to use IDs is another route. This way it would just be something like `#Guild.members.get(id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Guild.members.find()`. Since that contains the members, you will need to check whether the argument the user wrote matches the `.nickname` or the `.user.username`. To simplify things a little I will use `.displayName` instead of `.nickname`, so that I can always work with strings.

```
// argument: the string after the command, I don't know how you're currently getting it
let user = message.guild.members.find(m => [m.displayName.toLowerCase(), m.user.username.toLowerCase()].includes(argument.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: Thank you! I’m not at the computer right now, but I will totally be trying your answer out when I get home!